# Ask about how to use router nested in VuJs to pass params from one page to another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a nested router as follows:

```js
  {
    path: '/recruit',
    name: 'Recruit',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recruit" */ '../views/Recruit/index.vue'),
    children: [
      {
          path: "/recruit/:locale",
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recruit" */ '../views/Recruit/index.vue'),
      },
  ],
  },
```

When I click and change the locale params of the website to: localhost:8080/en and I want when I click to switch to any other page, it will still keep the locale params for example through the recruit page, it has the path as localhost:8080 /recruit/en, here's the link router I'm using:

```js
 <router-link
                class="nav-link rttr"
                :to="{ name: 'Recruit'}"
              >
                Tuyển dụng
              </router-link>
```

If you separate the above router into 2 separate routers, only recruit/:locale is active, and when the homepage does not have local params, it still leads to the /recruit page but the interface is still on the home page, and vice versa when I use a nested router, but I can't get the router params from the homepage to other sites. Thank you everyone for taking the time to read this post, hope to receive some help from everyone.

Comment: Could you please create a *runnable* [mcve] with what you have so far? Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: Actually what I want it's quite simple, for example I'm on the homepage as localhost:8080 I change my path to localhost:8080/en and when I redirect to another page it stays the same params /en wallet example from localhost:8080/en go to localhost:8080/page1/en.
Thank you for your input :( hope I get a solution to this problem soon

Comment: You seem to want to add a lang queryParam to every route. That's unusual, to say the least, especially if you plan on having nested routes and/or use other queryParams. Typically the language is added as a searchParam (e.g: ?lang=en). I asked you to create a [mcve] because it greatly improves your chances of getting help, because people don't need to create an example from scratch, they can just modify your example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<router-link
                class="nav-link rttr"
                :to="{ name: 'Recruit', params: {locale: 'en', page: 'page1} }"
              >
                Tuyển dụng
              </router-link>
```

Or just building your path dynamically, and using `path` instead of `name`.